# Error 103 en Pascal

Tags: pascal

Me compila el siguiente programa, pero me aparece el error 103. Creo que se refiere a que no se abrió el archivo. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? Pensé que era la dirección del archivo de texto pero al parecer está bien.

```
program ejercicio;


VAR

cont1: real;
archivo: text;
A: real;
B: Boolean;

begin
 assign(archivo,'/Users/tomasmatarazzo/programacion/ascendente.txt');
 reset(archivo);
 B := True;
 cont1 := 0;

 while not eof (archivo) do
 begin
     readLn(archivo,A);
     if A < cont1 then
         B := False
     else 
         cont1 := A;   

     close(archivo);
 end;
    if B then
       writeln('Los numeros se encuentran en forma ascendente')
    else
       writeln('Los numeros no se encuentran en forma ascendente');  

end.``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo lógico si reportas un error es dar la  mayor información posible.
El error 103 corresponde a:

```
 103 File not open

 Reported by the following functions : Close, Read, Write, 
 Seek, EOf, FilePos, FileSize, Flush, BlockRead, and BlockWrite 
 if the file is not open.
```

Tal y como dice al final de la documentación, este error ocurre **si el fichero no está abierto**. Por lo tanto es fácil deducir que en el punto donde se ha generado ese error, ese era el problema.

Si realizas un Debug de la ejecución paso a paso, verás que después de ejecutar el bucle la primera vez, en la segunda pasada generas este error. Es debido a que al fnal de la primera pasada del bucle lo cierras con:

```
 close(archivo);
```

Por lo tanto es normal que en la segunda pasada se encuentre cerrado y falle la llamada a `EOF`, tal y como dice la documentación.